# Can't fix nth-child margin

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a certain amount of divs class "box" floated next to eachother. Every 4n+1 th div has an extra left margin to push to lot away from to border by using the nth-child(4n+1) selector. There can be an infinite amount of divs class "box".

Problem is now that in some cases a div class "special" is dynamically added after a 4n-th element. This of course causes the next box-divs to lose their wanted position.
So then I tried nth-of-type without succes.

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="special"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Css for nth-child:

```
 .box:nth-child(4n+1){
  margin-left:25px;   
}
```

As I'm not so familiar with the nth-child and nth-of-type selector. So I'm pretty sure I'm overlooking something.
Adding an extra class to each 4n+1 box-div is not an option. I'm am looking for a css-solution

[Example without "special" div](http://jsfiddle.net/VdJmC/4/)

[Example with "special" div](http://jsfiddle.net/VdJmC/2/)

EDIT: The answer yet provided managed to solve 1 row after the special div. But net yet with multiple:
[Example multiple rows after "special"](http://jsfiddle.net/VdJmC/9/)

Hoping for as much browser compatibility as possible.

Comment: At the end I decided to add an extra class to every 4n +1 element. Was easier than expected. Yet I would love to see a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
.special + .box, 
.box:nth-child(4n+1) {
    margin-left:25px;
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/VdJmC/6/

If you change

```
<div class="special"></div>
```

to something else like

```
<p class="special"></p>
```

then following code will do exactly what you want (doesn't work till IE8)

```
.special + .box, 
.box:nth-of-type(4n+1) {
    margin-left:25px;
}
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/VdJmC/11/

Comment: `+` is immediate adjacency selector.

Comment: .special + .box means .box appearing immediately after .special

Comment: @AtifMohammedAmeenuddin Still seems a problem in the row right after the special div: jsfiddle.net/VdJmC/7

Answer (score 1):

Use instead

```
div > .box:first-child, 
.special + .box {
     margin-left:25px;   
}
```

it's a bit old-style than `nth-*`, but it would works even on `IE7`

Comment: could you explain the code for me? As you say it also works in IE7, I'll accept your answer. Also thanks atif for the working answer! EDIT: Without the special div, the second rows isn't intented... Atif's does.

Comment: Yes without it wouldn't work, but your question clearly says: *Adding an extra class to each 4n+1 box-div is not an option.*

Comment: uhu. But so still my problems isn't totally solved yet. Any more ideas, I would be glad to hear

Comment: ok, maybe you could update your fiddle with all possible markup and specify what browser do you need to support